# Creating a query for a report to bring in clients only if they have open accounts

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a query I am trying to use to give my users a list of only clients that currently have open accounts. The issue I am having is that it is bringing in ALL clients even if they do not have any current accounts. I feel like I am missing something simple here but so far have not been able to get this to work as intended.

```
SELECT Client.Client
FROM dbo.Client 
LEFT JOIN dbo.ClientLink On Client.Client = ClientLink.Client
LEFT JOIN dbo.ClientLink.ExternalId = AccountLink.ExternalId 
LEFT JOIN dbo.AccountLink.Account = Account.Account
GROUP By Client.Client
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Account.Closed IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Clearly the logic you are using does not  find open "current" accounts.  What might the correct logic be?

Comment: having no available data it would be difficult to answer this question but it may be that you need switch then 1 else 0 for then 0 else 1?

Comment: Having clause is wrong. Moreover why not to use `WHERE Account.Closed IS NOT NULL` ?

Comment: You should probably check the CASE condition for Account.Closed. Should it be NULL or something else?

Comment: I need to get only the client number. But only if they have open accounts. The way to judge this is each account has and 'opened' and 'closed' field. If the account is still open the closed field should be NULL. Any account without a NULL would have a 1 or greater and be included in the results.

Comment: I'm testing further to be sure but I believe it is working by changing the HAVING to (WHERE Account.Closed IS NULL) and adding DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that if clients have no accounts, then the links between the tables may be removed.  If so, the solution is to simply use `INNER JOIN`.

Your syntax is also all messed up.  But the query you want might be:

```
SELECT c.Client
FROM dbo.Client c JOIN
     dbo.ClientLink cl
     AccountLink al
     ON cl.ExternalId = al.ExternalId JOIN
     Account a
     ON a.Account = al.Account
GROUP By c.Client
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Account.Closed IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to rethink your query and how you are storing your data this is fundamental get this wrong then querying the database becomes a nightmare and you get unexpected results  for example does Account.Closed need to be null? if this was me I would create a default constraint that would set new accounts to be 0 (meaning open) then write a query to update accounts that needed to be closed and set this to 1.

again without really knowing how your schema looks providing an accurate answer is difficult.

I would then re-write the query to be.

```
SELECT Client.Client
FROM dbo.Client 
LEFT JOIN dbo.ClientLink On Client.Client = ClientLink.Client
LEFT JOIN dbo.ClientLink.ExternalId = AccountLink.ExternalId 
LEFT JOIN dbo.AccountLink.Account = Account.Account
WHERE Account.Closed = 0 --only return clients with opened accounts
```

if this is not possible to do then I would re-write your query as follows:

```
SELECT Client.Client, COUNT(Client.Client) AS NumberOfOpenAccounts
FROM dbo.Client 
LEFT JOIN dbo.ClientLink On Client.Client = ClientLink.Client
LEFT JOIN dbo.ClientLink.ExternalId = AccountLink.ExternalId 
LEFT JOIN dbo.AccountLink.Account = Account.Account
WHERE ISNULL(Account.Closed, 1) = 0 --only return clients with opened accounts
GROUP BY Client.Client
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking for is the client name, you can use DISTINCT instead of grouping. Something like the below statement might do the trick:

```
SELECT Distinct Client.Client
FROM Client 
INNER JOIN ClientLink On Client.Client = ClientLink.Client
INNER JOIN AccountLink On ClientLink.ExternalId = AccountLink.ExternalId 
INNER JOIN Account on AccountLink.Account = Account.Account
WHERE Account.Closed IS NULL
```

Hope this helps.